# Is it possible to register multiple accessors with the Tween Engine

Tags: java, tween

I'm using the Universal Tween Engine. So far I've been dealing with just one accessor (sprite accessor). However, now I have a need for two accessors. The second type of object is an extension of sprite. I've tried registering a new accessor for it, but the tween manager seems to use the sprite accessor instead.

Is this even possible? How does the tween manager decide which accessor to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your classes look like:

```
public class Sprite() { ... }
public class SubSprite extends Sprite() { ... }
```

You'd have to register the **specialised** accessor for the **specialised** `Sprite` (i.e.: the `SubSprite` class) ***BEFORE*** registering the accessor for the "generic" (i.e.: "super class") `Sprite`.

For example, you're probably doing:

```
Tween.registerAccessor(Sprite.class, new SpriteAccessor());
Tween.registerAccessor(SubSprite.class, new SubSpriteAccessor());
```

... while you should do:

```
Tween.registerAccessor(SubSprite.class, new SubSpriteAccessor());
Tween.registerAccessor(Sprite.class, new SpriteAccessor());
```

Cheers!